# Slow with using is.na as indexing

Tags: r

I am new to r (with experience in MatLab).  I'm still exploring with the syntax and learning to think in a R way.

I have some data (3000 x 3000) in data.frame class and the following code seems to perform very slow.

```
data[is.na(data)] = 0
```

I would like to get some comments on this from some experienced users. Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to convert `NA` to `0`?

Comment: Without seeing your code, it is rather hard to be precise, but a common mistake is to use a `data.frame` when you really just need a `matrix`. If everything is numeric (or integer), this would be considerably faster. Otherwise, try doing it only with the columns that require it, ala `data[is.na(data[,2]),2] = 0`.

Comment: What are the column classes? Are they all `numeric`?

Comment: @JeremyS - yes I am trying to convert NA to 0.

Comment: @RichardScriven - All columns are numeric

Comment: @r2evans - They are all numeric. ok, I will try to use more matrix than data.frame.  So array would also be faster?

Comment: `m <- as.matrix(data); m[is.na(m)] <- 0; data.frame(m)`

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon, odd, I've been doing it the hard way all these years ... thanks for the reference on `is.na<-`.

Comment: @user3639555, yes, in general arrays are faster than data frames.

Comment: @r2evans actually, I just realised that `is.na<-` can only be used to *set missingness*, i.e. turn elements to `NA` directly, rather than change to non-NA elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are just trying to replace `NA` with `0` and that you have all numbers, use a matrix.

```
x <- matrix(runif(9e+06,0,100),ncol=3000)
x[x <= 55 & x >= 54] <- NA
table(is.na(x))
  FALSE    TRUE 
8910086   89914
x[is.na(x)] <- 0
table(is.na(x))
  FALSE 
9000000
```

edit: the above conversion takes less than 1 second as a matrix, but still only 3 seconds as a data.frame (not including the table commands, which are the slowest parts there). What sort of time do you mean when you say very slow?

edit: response to Simon

```
system.time(is.na(x) <- 0)
user  system elapsed 
0.024   0.044   0.068 # yes faster
table(is.na(x))
FALSE    TRUE 
8909945   90055 # doesn't change x
system.time(x[is.na(x)] <- 0)
user  system elapsed 
0.252   0.032   0.287 # slower
table(is.na(x))
FALSE 
9000000 # changes x
```

Comment: how long was it taking before?

Comment: That doesn't change x for me. If I do `is.na(x) <- 0` then `table(is.na(x))` the result is x with the same number of `NA`

Comment: @JeremyS you are right. `is.na<-` sets missingness. Whoops. e.g. `is.na(x) <- 1` would set the first element of `x` to `NA`.